# delete token EasyAdmin 3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

i have a problem with the delete function in easyAdmin 3 in production.
the delete button refresh page and sending me at the home page.
i have found the delete function and the csrfToken send in the resuest is empty ?

```
$csrfToken = $context->getRequest()->request->get('token');
        if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('ea-delete', $csrfToken)) {
               dd($context);
            return $this->redirectToRoute($context->getDashboardRouteName());
        }
```

result :

```
^ EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext {#581 ▼
  -request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#12 ▼
    +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#15 ▶}
    +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#13 ▼
      #parameters: []
    }
    +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#14 ▶}
    +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#18 ▶}
```

do you have any idea plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the `action-delete` css class on the delete link/button ?

Without this class, you don't have the deletion confirmation popup and no CSRF token is sent in the deletion request, this is blocking the deletion process and redirecting you to the dashboard homepage.